# Associate program to a file where program is not in list

Tags: files, window-manager

I have a program (Guitar pro 6) that I want to associate to all `.gpx` files so that when i start such a file, it is started with that program.

Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't do that by default. It says it doesn't know which program to use and offers to identify that right program from a list. However, this program is not in the list.
Not to worry: so I read in this post

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1976921.html

How people solved this in 12.04
(By editing `/usr/share/applications/Guitar Pro 6.desktop` and adding `%u` to `Exec= line.`

However, in my situation (difference being the release level?) it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated

Cheers,
Mat

---

Update: I finally got word back from the GuitarPro support team:

*"About the file association issue, this seems to be more related to your computer, there is not feature in GP that will allow you to correct this. You might have to set your Linux Window manager to correct this."*

Well this is no help, obviously

Again: its an annoyance more then a huge problem but I'd still like to figure this one out. I'm running regular compiz window manager by the way.

Does anybody have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Select .gpx file>right-click>properties>Open with tab>search for GP6 executable.

Comment: Thanks for the response Uri! But also in your way, I am only offered a list of applications. I can't browse the file system for an applications that is not in that list.

Comment: Bunp! Still need help on this :)

Comment: I didn't think this should have been that difficult. I did some more research and am now looking at xdg-mime and xdg-open. Does anyone have pointers on that? Does it work in Ubuntu 12.10 and how to use syntax?

Comment: So far so bad: It was'nt even that big an issue. What was initialy a minor iritation is now driving me completely insane. I cannot believe this can't be fixed. This is where I'm at now:

I found my issue again (with a different applications, but that's not important right now) here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001865
The solution presented from post #4 onward seemed to work for a lot of people because i see a lot of refurals to this thread.

Comment: So I did a 'mimeopen -d'  to one of my .GPX files (Guitar Pro 6). As expected i get an option to associate a default application to it. So I go back to my Guitar Pro 6 .desktop config file in /usr/share/applications and look in the properties of the file to see how it launches: it has a redirect command to: /opt/GuitarPro6/launcher.sh . So, to association the file with GuitarPro, I put: GuitarPro6 /opt/GuitarPro6/launcher.sh.

Comment: Well as is to be expected by now: It doesn't work. Well what it did is that when i rightclick a .GPX file , the menu now contains a line: 'Open with GuitarPro6' But when I click that, nothing happens. I seems to me this application launcher doenst except parameters. Anyway, I'm on a mission from god now to solve this so again: ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.

Comment: What if you download GP6 for Windows an run it in Wine or is that what you're doing? If I recall GP6 works and I was able to use Guitar Pro tabs.

Comment: No I'm not using WINE now. That could be a way. Although I have problems with using WINE on principle. Besides GP is actualy stated as officaly suported on Ubuntu 9 and upwards. I guess I'll have a go at getting Arobas (the company that makes it) to resolve this, although I have a strong feeling that they will do the "its a feature, not a bug" routine on me. If that doenst work, i will give WINE a go. I will be sure to update this thread if this gets resolved. Thanks Uri.

Comment: Maybe you can give Ubuntu Tweak a chance. Look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/361446/associating-file-types-in-ubuntu-13-10/364592#364592.