# Associating file types in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, file-association

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to the latest release, saucy-salamander, also known as Ubuntu 13.10. I am facing problems with associating file types to applications. Instead of the traditional applications list that all the other versions of Ubuntu offered when a person is trying to associate a file to an application, Ubuntu 13.10 is giving me an option to search to the application executable.. which is rather frustrating.

[image]

[image]

How do i activate the old and traditional method whereby i have to chose an application directly without hunting down through the system for the executable...??

Comment: Can you try installing the `apturl` package (`sudo apt-get install apturl`). What type of file or link are you trying to open?

Comment: think you forgot to say that this is happening when you click on a special link inside a web browser

Comment: Minerz...already tried that, `apt-url` is already the latest version

Comment: The link is an apt:url type of link, that is supposed to redirect you to `Ubuntu Software Center` when you click on it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change all associations from gedit to another application](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115113/change-all-associations-from-gedit-to-another-application)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest Ubuntu-Tweak to configure the file associations, as Anwar Shah suggests here:  [Change all associations from gedit to another application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115113/change-all-associations-from-gedit-to-another-application).

First you must download the installer (a .deb file) from http://ubuntu-tweak.com/.
Then open the file and install the program from Ubuntu Software Center. Finally,
Open Ubuntu-Tweak an go to Admins -> File Type Manager.

At the list, look for your filetype and clic Edit -> Add to choose your custom application.

If you are trying to associate a Wine app (i. e. MS-Word to open .doc and .docx filetypes), you can add the application to the list if you edit the .desktop file located in ~/.local/share/applications/. Then, locate the "Exec=" parameter and, at the end of the line, add %U.

For MS-Word 2007:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Microsoft\ Office/Microsoft\ Office\ Word\ 2007.desktop
```

At the end of "Exec=" line, add %U. My file looks like this now:

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Name=Microsoft Office Word 2007
> Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/goghard/.wine_Office2007" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/goghard/.wine_Office2007/dosdevices/c:/users/goghard/Start\ Menu/Programs/Microsoft\ Office/Microsoft\ Office\ Word\ 2007.lnk **%U**
>
> Type=Application
>
> StartupNotify=true
>
> Comment=Create and edit professional-looking documents such as letters, papers, reports, and booklets by using Microsoft Office Word.
>
> Icon=2C1E_wordicon.0

For more detailed info, look the answer of user24185 at: [How to associate file types with wine in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270344/how-to-associate-file-types-with-wine-in-nautilus).

Answer (score 1):

I think i finally found a way....after a long struggle.

When the popup shows, and there are no apps to choose, you just go into the filesystem and choose the respective application from the `usr\bin` folder. In this case, the link was **`usr\bin\software-center`**. This should solve the problem.